# Firefox adds margin on the wrong element

Tags: html, css, firefox

Today I came across this code. It works as I would expect in Chrome, but it is adding a margin on a wrong element with Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      background-color: #aaa;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #header {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    #logo {
      float: left;
    }
    #menu {
      float: right;
    }
    .container {
      width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .main {
      margin-top: 36px;
    }
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">Logo</div>
        <div id="menu">Home</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container main">
       Content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Firefox seems to add the margin in the .main rule to the content div, which was expected, and to the header div too.

If I add some text inside the header it would work as expected and the header won't have that margin:

```
<div id="header"> Some text here
  <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
      <div id="menu">Home</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can also add some text after the header block and it would also do the trick for Firefox.

I can't figure out why is Firefox adding that margin to the header element.

Comment: Try making a http://jsfiddle.net out of it

Comment: You need to set the **padding** and **margin** of the header to 0;

Comment: The padding and margin doesn't seem to change anything. I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VfAq7/

Comment: @Fakito Try adding some `height` to the _header_ , [example](http://jsbin.com/emifOCi/1/edit).

Comment: I fixed it by adding min-height: 1em to the .header, but it still feels hacky. It seems like Firefox shouldn't be adding that margin after all.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange problem, I don't see why this happens.

It however seems to help when you add a `padding` of at least 1px to `.container`.

Also check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/CV2DU/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem has something to do with the container with automatic height and floating children...

Adding `display:inline-block;` to the `#header` will make it works in every browser (well except old IE), will include in the white box the right-floated div too (that now is not), and will continue to adjust the height automatically.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/VfAq7/1/

Comment: This seems to fix the header but the element's width is set to 960px, which is the container's width, and it doesn't set the margins so the element is not aligned.

Comment: I don't understand; the only differences I see are that the margins are gone, and the background is white for all the div, and not only up to the available screen size (try to run both of them this with a small fiddle window and move with the horizontal scrollbars)

Comment: Set the container's width to something like 260px to see what I mean. The header element won't be centered because the margins are set in the container, so I would need to set the margins to the header too.